# Issue with the name of a PostgreSQL table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql

The table in question is called "referentiel.adr_cad_numvoie_ponctuel" in the PostgreSQL database. But in QGIS, and this is the first time I've seen something like that, in the Browser panel, the table is displayed under the name "referentiel.adr_cad_numvoie_ponctuel.geometrie", I don't understand why there is this "geometrie" (which is the name of the geometry column). I don't understand what it is doing there. It is the only one of the many tables in the database, which is written this way in QGIS.

In PostgreSQL
[image]

In QGIS
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.  If you had multiple geometry columns in a table, the table would be listed several times with each geometry column.  This allows you to choose which geometry column you want displayed on the map.

Comment: Indeed, I did not realize it the first time. Thank you.